# Npm install error. How it might be solved

Tags: npm

When trying to run npm install I get following error as per print screen.

I've tried npm install --legacy-peer-deps / npm config set legacy-peer-deps true/ node.js downgrade but nothing seems to be working. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBeBy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQj2t.png)

Comment: please post code and error messages as text and not as image